# Javascript: How to Detect if browser window is scrolled at bottom on android device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing lazy load functionality in my application.
It is working properly on the iPhone, desktop, tab.
But not working on an android phone.
Below is my code for calculating bottom -

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
 var scrollHeight, scrollPosition;
 scrollHeight = $(document).height();
 scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
 if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
    this.get_data();
 }
});
```

I have also tried below option but still not able to calculate bottom on android.

```
if($(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height() < 50) {
   this.get_data();
 }
```

Comment: @Taplar I have edited the code, please check again. Actually doing it in CoffeeScript and just converted my code and added here that's why "return" keyword was their.

Comment: That's cool, so still as a side note, you should consider caching your jQuery constructors that are repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
Actually logic is correct not issue with it.
But have gone through the HTML and CSS and got to know that my HTML is breaking and because of that i was getting wrong scrollTop() and document height.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I think is happening:

When you scroll down to the end of a document in Chrome on Android, it hides the address bar. This causes a dimension change which you're not always picking up because you're not listening for a `resize` event -- just `scroll`. That's pretty dumb on the browser side in my opinion.

Anyway:

```
function update() {
    // ...all your awesome code here
}

$(window).on('resize', update); // look out world, magic happening here
$(window).on('scroll', update);
```

And, for an example... (I cleaned this up a bit during testing):

```js
var $status = $('#status');
var $window = $(window);
var $document = $(document);

function update() {
  var maxScrollTop = $document.height() - $window.height();
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

  var calc = maxScrollTop - scrollTop;

  if (calc < 50) {
    $status.html('Load more!!');
  } else {
    $status.html(calc);
  }
}

$window.on('scroll', update);
$window.on('resize', update);
```

```css
#content {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
}

#status {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
<div id="status">Scroll to start</div>
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: It's still not working on the android device. Problem is not with scroll event, scroll event works on android too but I think the issue in the calculation.

Comment: @Kalashir I initially ran the code through an emulator and just ran it on my own Android device this morning -- and it works. This might be a device or browser-specific bug; I'm using Chrome on a Galaxy. [Here's a CodePen link](https://s.codepen.io/shengslogar/debug/KEaoYG/GnMnbNKKEvQM) if you want to test that.