# Detecting if scrolled to bottom on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I need to detect that a user has scrolled to the bottom of a scrollable `div`. I assumed that the code below should work fine, and it does on a desktop computer, but not on a mobile device (Android, Chrome browser in this case).

```js
var scrolledToEnd = el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop === el.clientHeight
```

The scrollable `div` has `overflow` set to `auto`. It's clientHeight is `150px`.

**Desktop outcome when scrolled to bottom**

- `el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop` is `150`
- `el.clientHeight` is `150`

**Mobile outcome when scrolled to bottom**

- `el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop` is `149.90476`
- `el.clientHeight` is `150`

Why is the outcome on a mobile device different? Is there a way to make this work on mobile as well? I haven't come up with an solution so far.

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just wrap it in [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) or [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)? `Math.ceil(el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop)`

Comment: The problem is that in a different case (987 pixels) the outcoume is 987.8736. This is an example case, but the outcome can be higher, or lower. So this won't work in all cases.

Comment: Implement a bit of a tolerance interval then? Checking that the absolute difference is less than one pixel should probably do it.

Comment: Or just use `>=` instead of `===`

Comment: Can be lower as well @Reyno

Comment: This difference is most likely to be within one pixel. Which means that `Math.ceil` + `>=` will catch most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
var scrolledToEnd = el.scrollHeight - Math.round(el.scrollTop) === el.clientHeight;
```

If you read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) you will notice

> On systems using display scaling, `scrollTop` may give you a **decimal** value.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029780/349604

Need to do a combination of rounding the `scrollTop` value and listening to `resize` events as well as `scroll`.

Be aware that (on Android browsers at least) `clientHeight` doesn't seem to respond to `resize` events, but `window.innerHeight` does (though on Android Chrome only after scrolling stops...).

Comment: Very helpful info, thank you James!